# Direct product of $D2$ and $D3$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups, direct-product

I am trying to find information on the group resulting from the direct product of the dihedral groups $D2$ (Klein four-group) and $D3$ (or, isomorphic: $S_3$ or $C_{3v}$).

What would be the resulting group? I am especially interested in the irreducible representations of the result.

Thanks!

Comment: This direct product is isomorphic to (in your notation) $D6 \times \Bbb Z_2$. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_D12_and_Z2

Comment: Thanks! Would that be equivalent to $D_{6h}$, which is used in crystallography?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the representations of $S_{3}$ and $K_{4}$, then it is easy to find the irreducible representations of their direct product. It is basically  the tensor product of the irreducible representations of the individual groups. So $K_{4}$ has four irreducible representations of degree 1, $S_{3}$ has two degree one irreducible representations and one degree 2 irreducible representation. So take their tensor product and obtain all the irreducible representation of the direct product. So possible degree will be 1,2 or 4. You can consult any standard representation theory book (e,g Character theory of finite group- I.M Isaacs -Chapter 4) to find a proof of this fact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was only aware of tensor products of irreps of the same group -- so the character of some element  $(g,h)$ would be given by $\chi(g) * \chi(h)$?

Comment: Yes it's defined the same way for two different groups too! ?If $\chi_{1}$ and $\chi_{2}$ be two characters of representation of $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ respectively then the tensor product of these two representations is a representation of the group $G_{1}\times G_{2}$ having character $\chi_{3}((g_{1},g_{2}))=\chi_{1}(g_{1})\chi_{2}(g_{2})$